# Check status of Caps Lock in Python

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks, text-object

I'm making a script which allows the user to change the contents of a Text Object as if it were a Textbox in a Word Document.

Is there a way to check what the status of the Caps Lock button is, so that i know whether it's on or not.

Or, is there a better way to have a textbox in a game?

Comment: I actually don't see a way to tell whether the caps lock is enable, only if the key is up or down.

Comment: But that just checks as to whether it has been pressed. Therefore if the player starts the game with Caps Lock on, the results would be different than if they started the game with it off.